# ServiceStack MVC automatically registering routes

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, servicestack

I seem to be unable to get my services to be automatically routed,   MetaData  shows all the classes and services available, however should I go to  /api/btbCustomerEvents   I get the unhandled route error.

I have tried this:

```
[Alias("btbCustomerEvents")]
[RestService("/btbCustomerEvents")]
public class Btbcustomerevent : BaseModel
```

my AppHost  looks like this:

```
public class AppHost: AppHostBase
{       
    public AppHost() : base("Energy System API", typeof(DepartmentService).Assembly) { }

    public override void Configure(Funq.Container container)
    {
        //Set JSON web services to return idiomatic JSON camelCase properties
        ServiceStack.Text.JsConfig.EmitCamelCaseNames = true;

        //register all routes
        Routes
            .Add<Department>("/Departments")
            .Add<Department>("/Departments/{Id}")
            .Add<Paymentmethod>("/PaymentMethods")
            .Add<Paymentmethod>("/PaymentMethods/{Id}")
            .Add<MyExampleModel>("/MyExampleModel")
            .Add<MyExampleModel>("/MyExampleModel/{Id}");

        //Change the default ServiceStack configuration
        SetConfig(new EndpointHostConfig{ DebugMode = true, });

        container.Register<ICacheClient>(new MemoryCacheClient());
        container.Register<ISessionFactory>(c => 
            new SessionFactory(c.Resolve<ICacheClient>()));

        ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new FunqControllerFactory(container));
    }

    public static void Start()
    {
        new AppHost().Init();
    }
```

I dont really want to add in the routes for everything, I have created TT files that create  the models from the database, and also automatically adds the rest services / CRUD style,  it just seems a shame that now I have to manually add each, and every route.

Anyone have a solutions for this?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, automation registration of routes is already built into ServiceStack. Using the `Routes.AddFromAssembly()` extension method it will register custom routes for all services in the assemblies specified (for all the verbs you have implementations for), e.g:

```
//    /{RequestDto}
//    /{RequestDto}/{Id} - if Id exists
Routes.AddFromAssembly(typeof(Department).Assembly);
```

See the [implementation for Routes.AddFromAssembly()](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.ServiceInterface/ServiceRoutesExtensions.cs#L26) for a template of how you can auto-register your own routes if you have different heuristics.

Comment: HI, thanks   i get error: Exception Details: System.Reflection.AmbiguousMatchException: Property names are case-insensitive: DbaIndexdefraglog.ErrorMessage   but the case and spelling are correct?  have tried with service too but get the same error message.  I put the code inside AppHost / Configure just before the other routes I had made, could you be a bit more specific on were this goes,   thanks

Comment: This is a replacement for manually registering routes. i.e. Remove any Routes that look like `/{RequestDto}` and `/{RequestDto}/{Id}` because the above line of code already does this for every service in the specified assemblies.

Comment: Hi thanks,  yeah I did that, it falls over, does not like some of the tables and I am only able to upgrade the code and not the database so far,  one thing I did notice is that base("Energy System API", typeof(DepartmentService).  should not have pointed to the service, so I corrected this and amended my TT files to add RestService links automatically, thanks for your help